# Can a silk touch pickaxe be used in a quarry?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

Silk Touch isn't exactly a *rare* enchantment, but it's far between enough that I'd rather not waste a silk pick in an experiment; I'm hoping someone else has tried this (with success).

The main crafting ingredient in a BuildCraft quarry is an undamaged diamond pickaxe. I was able to use one that had the Silk Touch enchantment. Now, before I go committing to unleashing this on a 64x64 area, will the quarry give me ores instead of ingots? To be clear, I *was* able to craft it using the enchanted pick.

I *can* deconstruct the quarry if this isn't going to work using a deconstruction table; I would be awful sore if I ended up losing a brand new silk touch pick for nothing :)

Comment: Are you using BuildCraft only? Or are you using a modpack like FTB?

Comment: @Ben Not using FTB, but I am playing about two dozen mods that I've picked out to test.

Comment: Well if you're using Thaumcraft, they have a more advanced version of the Quarry called a Bore. This can use Picks with enchants, and can mine in all directions (x, y and z). Trouble is you have to research it.

Comment: @TimPost the next time you wish to 'experiment' without wasting your valuable lewts, use creative mode!

Comment: @Ender I thought of that, but (1) I hate cheating things into the game, even for the sake of science and (2) I thought that I can't be the only person to ever wonder about this, so it might be a good bit of information to have around :) Plus, if I hadn't asked, I wouldn't have learned that Thaumcraft existed, and someone with this question would equally appreciate learning that it does.

Comment: @TimPost I personally never play in creative, and also hate cheating things in, however I keep a creative world on hand usually to 'experiment' when I'm unsure of how a particular mechanic properly works.

Comment: I also have a creative world that I use for making complex circuitry in RedPower so I can work out how it would be designed before attempting to make it in survival mode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. It won't. Quite simply, the recipe does not take enchantments into account.

Comment: I doubt this is possible, but can you enchant the quarry to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: No. No enchanting in BuildCraft.

Comment: As an aside, you also won't be able to get that enchanted pick back either. The deconstruction table would have to somehow know that the pick used was enchanted, and it does not.

Comment: @MikeCaron Something I realized, to great agony, when attempting to do just that. Oh well, it was worth losing one to learn that I'd end up losing one, I suppose.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have quarry with silk touch enchantment you should install [QuarryPlus](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1756982-164sspsmpforgeyogpstops-mods-quarryplusand-more/) mod (BuildCraft addon). It adds more powerful and faster quarries (with maximal quarry area 256 x 256 blocks) and ability to add enchantments like efficiency, silk touch, fortune, etc to those quarries.

Comment: That's a lot of chunks to keep loaded, how many have you run at once?

Comment: @TimPost You can also just use a 64x64 area. The 256x256 area is just the maximumsize. And it loads them and also doesn't load them. It's kinda weird.

Answer (score 1):

Quarries are not considered tools by Minecraft, and therefore cannot carry enchantments. Mods like Thaumcraft and Thermal Expansion have features that will mine with arbitrary enchantmants.

Answer (score 0):

Buildcraft doesn't do silk touch, unfortunately. As mentioned elsewhere, the QuarryPlus mod has a silk touch feature, and Mekanism's digital miner can be used like a quarry and silk-touch ores. The Modjam entry Progressive Automation, available on [this page](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/modjam/projects.php?type=Mod), supports quarrying using any set of enchantments on a tool. If you don't care for magic blocks that do everything for you, several block breakers can use enchantments, such as TE3's autonomous activators and I think something from Immibis's TubeStuff. Minefactory Reloaded has block breakers that, IIRC, can use enchantments given mob essence. As for the block moving, [Redstone in Motion](http://forums.technicpack.net/topic/45317-16x15x-redstone-in-motion-redpower-frames-2300-october-8/) or my continuation fork [Remain in Motion](http://forums.technicpack.net/topic/59545-16x-remain-in-motion-continuation-of-redstone-in-motion/) will do it pretty elegantly, MFFS will do it too ([tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFG13.jpg)), and probably a few other mods can do it.